# Create a collapsible card component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to present a few different types of information, in separate cards. Each Card, needs to be able to open and close when clicking on the Header.

Up until now, I wrote this piece of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

// Importing Styles
import './styles.scss';

class CardToggle extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };

    this.handleToggleClick = this.handleToggleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !isOpen
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="card my-2 border-0 rounded-0">
        <div className="card-body d-flex">
          <h4>
            <a className="text-secondary" href="">
              {title}
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardToggle;
```

I have a few problems though. There is an error, regarding `handleToggleClick` not being defined. Also, every component I use inside this component is not being placed inside the card body: It is placed underthing...

So, I need to actually place the content of the component I want to make appear and disappear inside the component, and make the collapse component work.

I am using pure `Bootstrap 4` classes, for cards and header and text, and I want to use pure react for the functionality of open/close....

Here is an example component I want to  insert into card component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CardToggle from '../CardToggle';

import { ThePermissions } from '../../constants';

class Permissions extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CardToggle title="Permissions" />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> // From 
         here it is outside the card
        <div>
        More Content here
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Permissions;
```

Can anyone give me a hand. I don't want to use a library and I want the component to be reusable. I also want to handle additional logic regarding `show/hide`, in the main overview screen which is already huge.

If you want to see that as well, just ping me.

Comment: I want to add, that I don't want an accordion. It doesn't suit either the design or the functionality of the screen. It must be cards, and be able to be reused in multiple screens.

Comment: please show us how are you using `handleToggleClick`, you have a bug inside the method, you can't do `isOpen: !isOpen`, the negated `isOpen` is undefined since you don't have a variable with that name, you shoud do `isOpen: !this.state.isOpen`, and is not a good practice either, you should use the callback function, since you are using the value of the state to generate a new one, and `setState` is async, 
a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/ywkzpj1x7x

Answer (score 0):

1.For the error of undefined, instead of

```
handleToggleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: !isOpen
    });
};
```

try

```
handleToggleClick() {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: !isOpen
    });
}
```

2.for the content not appearing inside the component try:

```
render() {
    const { title, children } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="card my-2 border-0 rounded-0">
        <div className="card-body d-flex">
            <h4>
            <a className="text-secondary" href="">
                {title}
            </a>
            </h4>
            <div className="/*some class*/">
                 {children} // this is where the content will be shown 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: For the second issue. You are right. For the first though, the `handleToggleClick`, it says the same error. `handleToggleClick` is not defined`. Funny thing is, I am doing it exactly as the React docs say to do it... Thanks though. You helped a lot..